# How do i return Django queryset only if value exists in another table?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Maybe the late hour has my brain fried because I am sure this is incredibly easy. I want to return a queryset of all candidates that are in the the CallList of a particular Prospecting. My view is being passed the Prospecting id. I have read many posts on values and value lists, but I am struggling. Any help would be appreciated.

Candidate.objects.filter(????)

```
class Prospecting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class CallList(models.Model):
    prospecting = models.ForeignKey(Prospecting, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Candidate(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Note**: first_name and last_name is already present in django's default User model. You can use this if you want.

### ---- Edit from here ----

1) Add related name in both ForeignKey fields (please use different and better names). Also, you should use `related_name` in `ForeignKey` and `OneToOne` fields. We can also use `_set`, but I prefer **related_name**.

```
class CallList(models.Model):
    prospecting = models.ForeignKey(Prospecting, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='prosp_name')
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cand_name')
```

If you you are using function based function, try this:

```
def func_name(request, prospecting_id):
   qry = Candidate.objects.filter(cand_name__prospecting__pk=prospecting_id)
```

If you also want to check if user is logged in (there will be only one user for one request, so technically it will return queryset only if user is logged in and logged in user satisfy the condition otherwise it will return `None`). (If you want all candidates related to prospecting_id through call list, you should not check the logged in user.)

```
from django.db.models import Q
def func_name(request, prospecting_id):
   filt = Q(cand_name__prospecting__pk=prospecting_id) & Q(user=request.user)
   qry = Candidate.objects.filter(filt)
```

I hope this will work, if not please reply.

Comment: My apologies...it was late and my question was not asked correctly. There is a 3rd table, Prospecting, and that is the id I receive. So I want to get a queryset of all candidates for a particular prospecting item through the call list table. I fixed my question.

Comment: @ChristopherGeorge, I have edited the answer. Please check if this works.you can use value_list() if requires.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best solution, but I got it working with the following:

list = Candidate.objects.filter(pk__in=CallList.objects.filter(Q(user=self.request.user) & Q(prospecting=Prospecting.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['tagid']))).values_list('candidate'))

Where tagid is the id in Prosepcting. Note: User and Candidate are different tables. User is in the Candidate table since this is a multi-tenant site. Thanks for your help.